# How can I create a popup at a given buffer line and column when the wrap option is set?

Tags: wrapping, line-numbers, popup

When you do [`popup_create`](https://vimhelp.org/popup.txt.html#popup_create%28%29)`({whatever}, #{ line: m, col: n})`, `m` and `n` are meant to be *screen* column numbers, as per [`:help popup_create-arguments`](https://vimhelp.org/popup.txt.html#popup_create-arguments).

But what if I want to position the popup at a specific document line and column?

Well, `line:` and `col:` can be given `'cursor±offset'`, which is basically a way to change the origin from which `line` and `col` are counted, and since the offset from the cursor can be computed as `[desiredline - line('.'), desiredcol - col('.')]`, one can craft the two `'cursor±offset'` strings **carefully** to put the popup where they want.

By **carefully** I mean that one needs to take care of `+` and `-`, which is probably not that hard.

But what makes the thing so hard are two points:

1. How do I detect (in order to abort the creation) if the position where I want to put the popup in the given buffer is

   - out of the terminal window?
   - within the terminal window but out of the current Vim window?
2. **Most importantly**, how in the world do I deal with the case of `wrap` being turned on?

I'd be tempted [to open a request](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues) (I'm checking if one exists already) for having one of these:

- `popup_create` to accept the text line and text column numbers for easy positioning it with respect to text
- a general `to_screenpos` function accepting a text line and text column numbers and converting them to a position on the screen, which would allow preprocessing `[line('.') ± offset, col('.') ± offset]` before passing it to `popup_create`; it could even result in `[]` to communicate that position is not visible, so one could not call `popup_create` in that case.

but I'd like to see if a handy solution exits already.